# Как распознать движение страницы вниз или вверх с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите метод или комбинацию методов jquery, отлавливающий вертикальное направление прокрутки страницы вверх или вниз. Не просто прокрутку типа scroll, а именно направление прокрутки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отлавливает когда скроллитсья вниз и вверх

```js
(function () {
    let previousScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(() => {
       let currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       currentScroll > previousScroll ? alert('Идем вниз') : alert('Поднимаемсья  вверх');
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

```css
div {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>:) </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', (evt)=>{
 console.log(evt.deltaY);
});
```

На ванильном JS можно повесить обратотчик `wheel` и сделадить за значение `evt.deltaY`. Если оно больше `0` значит скролл идет вниз, если меньше тогда вверх.